# Weird Issue Facing Upcon Google oAuth Completioin

Tags: php, security, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

i am trying to get google account access from user using oAuth, i was using from long time no issues. But on a new project/site, when user try to give oAuth access, all goes fine at google end but when google return the "code" to my script/page it shows 403, please check the screenshot..

[image: Google oAuth Error]

and more surprisingly. after that error comes up my site and no other pages working..  here is the screenshot:

[image]

even more surprisingly if i try the my site/page again on a new computer it does work, but as soon i try the oAuth part it shows that same error and on that computer my site stops working at all on that computer as well. Now i am out of computer to try anymore and find out the issue. :(

even i can't connect with ftp and/or cPanel.

and i am damn confused what can caused that?

any idea?

best regards